# Trouble with one reg add in a batch file

Tags: batch-file, regedit

I have a batch file with two reg add commands in it. Both seem to work but one will show in the registry for about 5 seconds and then disappears. I have tried all the formatting styles and cannot get the one to stick. Here are the two reg adds I'm using:

```
 reg add HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run /v CrashPlanTray /t REG_SZ /d C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Local\Programs\CrashPlan\electron\CrashPlanDesktop.exe --menubar --desktop=false --user.install
```

and

```
 reg add HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run /v CrashPlanServiceUser /t REG_SZ /d C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Local\Programs\CrashPlan\CrashPlanService.vbs
```

It is the first one CrashPlanTray that will not stick.

I have tried it adding the `\` before the data value and at the end of the data value. It will add it to the registry but then after a few seconds it disappers.

```
 reg add HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run /v CrashPlanTray /t REG_SZ /d "\"C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Local\Programs\CrashPlan\electron\CrashPlanDesktop.exe\" --menubar --desktop=false --user.install
```

I have been trouble shooting and working with this for days now. I can get it to work and stick from a command window but once I put it in the batch file it no longer sticks. I could use some expert help in figuring out why it won't stick in the registry?

Answer (score 1):

On the first reg add, try this:

```
reg add HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run /v CrashPlanTray /t REG_SZ /d "\"%localappdata%\Programs\CrashPlan\electron\CrashPlanDesktop.exe\" --menubar --desktop=false --user.install"
```

Take special note of the double quotes (beginning and end) enclosing the full string to registry, as well as the escaped ones enclosing the path ( I shortened the above path for demonstration purpose:

```
"\"%localappdata%\..\CrashPlanDesktop.exe\" --menubar --desktop=false --user.install"
```

Finally, also notice we can use `%localappdata%` instead of `C:\users\%username%\..`

Comment: `%appdata%` is NOT `C:\users\%username%\Appdata\local`. It's `C:\users\%username%\Appdata\Roaming`. And I believe it's not wise to put the script into a roaming profile.

Comment: @montonero thanks for highlighting that, I type without thinking sometimes. updated.

Comment: I don't really want to put this in Roaming. It is essentially two registry entries I am removing to disable crashplan when people are in countries where internet is not cheap or bandwidth is poor. When they return to their home country I am just trying to put back what was removed. My users are not technical and I need simple solutions (i.e. Stop.bat & Start.bat without any user interactions except of course to run the batch file.).

Comment: @RSquared I already updated it to goto local, not roaming, was just a simple mistake while I typed the answer.

Comment: OK, tried your answer and same results. The problem isn't getting it into the registry with the correct values ... the problem is getting it to stay in the registry for more that 10 seconds. It goes it and then disappears. It won't "stick". (I Probably should not use words like stick as its possible not everyone understands them properly.)

Comment: @RSquared, if it is being removed from your registry after being correctly added, the issue is outside of the scope of this forum. We fix problematic code, not identify the actions of your unspecified policies or antimalware software. I have therefore voted to close your question because we cannot reproduce the issue, or your environment, _(given the information you have provided)_.

Answer (score 0):

First thing I'd do is because the locations use environment variables is to use `REG_EXPAND_SZ`, instead of `REG_SZ`.

I'd use backslashes to then escape any internal doublequotes and protect the locations, as they could contain things like spaces.

I'd set the common strings as values at the top to make it easier to modify and shorten the lines somewhat, and would also probably use carets, **`^`** to shorten the lines still further for readability.

Finally, if you're wanting to run a `VBScript` from the registry run key, you should really be running it from either `WScript.exe` or `CScript.exe`. My example below uses `WSCript`, but you can replace that with `CScript` and any required options as needed.

```bat
@Set "Key=HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run"
@Set "Loc=%%LocalAppData%%\Programs\CrashPlan"
@Reg Add "%Key%" /V "CrashPlanTray" /T REG_EXPAND_SZ /D^
 "\"%Loc%\electron\CrashPlanDesktop.exe\" --menubar --desktop=false --user.install" /F>Nul
@Reg Add "%Key%" /V "CrashPlanServiceUser" /T REG_EXPAND_SZ /D^
 "WScript \"%Loc%\CrashPlanService.vbs\"" /F>Nul
```

Comment: I am trying to put it back exactly like it was when CrashPlan installed it. I have a batch file that does this for when CP was installed for All Users (the default install) and it works flawlessly. This is for users who chose to install it for a Single User so it alters the location of some things and it is not your normal service which can be controlled and edited using SC. Sorry, I guess I should have provided a little more background on the original entry for a more comprehensive understanding. My Bad :(

Comment: Thank you for your comment @RSquared. I've provided code that will create your entries correctly and included additional advice to improve upon what you had before, if you don't want to accept my advice, you don't have to, its your question and your choice.

Comment: OK, this is very interesting. It seems to stick until I actually start the service. This has me thinking that maybe I don't fully understand what is going on with these two registry entries (i.e. the parameter --user.install ???). I am going to look at these some more later. Maybe Monday as I have plans for tomorrow and the weekend. When I ran these as is ... the %%LocalAppData%% gets written to the registry value as: WScript "%LocalAppData%\Programs\CrashPlan\CrashPlanService.vbs". Doesn't seem like the LocalAppData variable is a valid system variable??? You have me thinking in a new way now!

Comment: @RSquared, open a Command Prompt Window and enter `Set` to see all of the variables in your environment. If you want to speed up the process, enter `Set L` to see all variables beginning with the letter `L`. When you use a `REG_EXPAND_SZ` key, the variable is expanded when the data string is actually run, instead of it being sat there as an already expanded string, `REG_SZ`.

Comment: Using the SET in a command window I can see %LOCALAPPDATA% and it contains the correct value. I don't know exactly what has changed but after completely uninstalling and reinstalling CrashPlan and then running the batch files to disable and re-enable it all is now working correctly. Your efforts were not wasted as I am using snippets of the things you suggested in my revised batch files and it makes them much cleaner to read and work with. Thank you for your help and patience.

Comment: @RSquared, f you're not willing to accept an answer as your solution, but you've decided to implement some of the above advice into your end product, I would ask that you at least upvoted the answer in order to show some appreciation for the time and effort I have afforded to you and your issue.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly what has changed but after completely uninstalling and reinstalling CrashPlan, all is working again. I can now run the batch files to disable and re-enable it they are now working correctly. Your efforts were not wasted as I am using snippets of the things you suggested in my revised batch files and it makes them much cleaner to read and work with. Thank you for your help and patience.